# disable addEventListener for mobile/smaller screen devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a navigation component that has hidden navigation items until you scroll to a certain point in the viewport. `isTop` looks for the position on the page and once its reached the nav items fade in. On a mobile or tablet menu I want them to be visible all the time.

Is there a method to detect if a user is on a smaller screen size and if they are you can disable an event listener?

Snippet:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.updateWindowDimensions();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
  document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const isTop = window.scrollY < window.innerHeight - 50;
    if (isTop !== this.state.isTop) {
      this.setState({ isTop })
    }
  });
}
```

```
<NavItem className={this.state.isTop ? 'hide' : 'show fadeIn'}>
  <NavLink className="active" href="/">Home</NavLink>
</NavItem>
<NavItem className={this.state.isTop ? 'hide' : 'show fadeIn'}>
  <NavLink href="/option">Option</NavLink>
</NavItem>
<NavItem className={this.state.isTop ? 'hide' : 'show fadeIn'}>
  <NavLink href="/option2">Option 2</NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

Comment: There is a screen object in the window object. Please refer to, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could use `window.matchMedia` to see if the window matches (or doesn't match) a certain width. In your case for example:

`const isMobile = !window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 768px)').matches`

This code above would return true if the window is smaller than 768px, IE smaller than a tablet.

You could then store `isMobile` in state and use that to check if the device is a mobile.

Comment: Alright but, if you check for the size and true is returned. How do you set isTop to be false?

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you mean, you could just do `!isMobile`?


If you want to check both `!isMobile` and `isTop`, you could do a check on `!isMobile  && isTop`?

Comment: Never mind its unrelated, I like your answer. I didn't use it exactly as written but thanks for pointing me in the right direction